# Issue in moving a drupal 7 website from server to localhost

Tags: drupal-7

I want to change my drupal website to run in localhost.I just downloaded files and put it in my localhost and installed drupal.But links in website shows 404.Can any one tell me what's real problem is.I changed the .htacess file with old one.still shows 404 links.

Comment: What are the URLs that you're trying to get to?  Do they exist on the localhost in the paths that are being referred to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need switch on mod_rewrite in apache httpd.conf?

Comment: I just switch on mod_rewrite but still same problem